# EventEmitter and ag-grid-angular How to use the `emit` method in` ag-grid-angular`

Tags: angular, eventemitter, ag-grid-angular

How to use the `emit` method in`ag-grid-angular`. In `ag-grid-angular` I have buttons that should hide alternately and when clicking on another line.

When I click on another line the button does not change.

I try using the method `emit`, but I can't see it in my another component `ButtComponent` where I have buttons. I do not know if that's a good idea.

gridComponent.component.html:

```
   <ag-grid-angular   
        (rowSelected)="onRowSelected($event)"  
        [rowSelection]="rowSelection" 
        (selectionChanged)="onSelectionChanged($event)" 
        [suppressChangeDetection]='true' 
        #agGrid 
        style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" 
        id="uprawnieniaGrid" 
        class="ag-theme-balham" 
        [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
        [rowData]="rowData" 
        [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents"
         (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)">
    </ag-grid-angular>
```

gridComponent.component.ts:

```
export class GridComponent implements OnInit { 

      @Output() eventEmitter: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
      rowData:any;   
      frameworkComponents: any; 
      gridApi?: GridApi;
      columnApi?: ColumnApi; 
      columnDefs:any;

      constructor( private dataService: DataService ) {

        this.frameworkComponents = {      
          buttons: ButtComponent,
          col5RenderComponent: Col3RenderComponent,
        };

        this.columnDefs = [{
          headerName: '',     
          headerCheckboxSelection: true,
          checkboxSelection: true, 
        }, {
          headerName: 'col 1',       
          field: 'col1'         
        }, {
          headerName: 'col 2', 
          field: 'col2'
        }, {
          headerName: 'col 3 ',     
          field: 'col3',      
          editable: true,
          cellRenderer: 'col3RenderComponent'    
        }, {
          headerName: "Edition",
          field: "value",
          cellRenderer: "buttons",
          colId: "edition"      
        }
        ];

      }

       ngOnInit() {
        this.dataService.dataList().subscribe(dataList => {
          if (dataList.data) {
              this.rowData = dataList.data;
          }
        });
       }

      onGridReady(params: any) {    
        this.gridApi = params.api;
        this.columnApi = params.columnApi;
        params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();   
      } 


      onSelectionChanged(event: any) {
        var rowCount = event.api.getSelectedNodes().length;
        console.log("selection changed, " + rowCount + " rows selected");
      }

      onRowSelected(event: any) {
        console.log("row " + event.node.data.id + " selected = " + event.node.selected);
       if (event.node.selected == false){
        this.eventEmitter.emit('Register click');
        console.log('EMIT');

       }
      }
    }
```

ButtComponent.component.html:

I have buttons here, but the `eventEmitterTemp` method is not called.

```
 <i (click)="onClick1($event)" (eventEmitter)='eventEmitterTemp($event)' *ngIf="isShowButton.val1" class='fa fa-edit'  ></i>  
 <i (click)="onClick2($event)" *ngIf="isShowButton.val2" class='fa fa-save' ></i>
```

buttComponent.component.ts:

```
export class ButtComponent implements ICellRendererAngularComp  {

      params: any;
      isShowButton = {
        val1: true,
        val2: false
      };

      agInit(params: any): void {
        this.params = params;     
      }

      constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

      refresh(params: any): boolean {

        this.isShowButton.val1 = false;
        this.isShowButton.val2 = true;
        console.log('refresh');
        return true;
      }


      onClick1($event: any) {
        this.isShowButton.val1 = false;
        this.isShowButton.val2 = true;

        const startParams = {
          rowIndex: this.params.data.id - 1,
          colKey: 'col4'
        };
        this.params.api.startEditingCell(startParams); 
      }


      onClick2($event: any) {

        this.isShowButton.val1 = true;
        this.isShowButton.val2 = false;

        this.dataService.dataSet().subscribe(dataList => { 
            if (dataList.data) {
                this.rowData = dataList.data;
            }
        });
      }

        eventEmitterTemp($event: any){

        this.isShowButton.val1 = false;
        this.isShowButton.val2 = true;
            console.log('-----EMIT GET 1');
        }

    }
```

How to run the `eventEmitterTemp` method from the `GridComponent` component from the `onRowSelected` method when the condition is met:
`if (event.node.selected == false)`

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it would be really helpful if you posted a full running example, on say, StackBlitz.

However, I think that your issue is your attempt to bind to 'eventEmitter', i.e. your code: 
`<i (click)="onClick1($event)" **(eventEmitter)='eventEmitterTemp($event)**' *ngIf="isShowButton.val1" class='fa fa-edit'  ></i>`

As far as I know, given the code that you've shown, that should produce a compiler error.
I'm not really sure what you meant it to do...

If you want the code in the `eventEmitterTemp` method to be executed when the button is clicked, why not just either add that code to one of the click handler methods (onClick1 or onClick2, or both, depending on what you want to do)?

It seems to me that you have an additional design problem here.
Your 'ButtComponent' is a cell renderer, but you have it calling services, and apparently trying to interact with the grid (changing grid rows, etc.)

Interaction with the grid should be done in it's parent component, and the renderer should be kept really simple - just present the buttons, enable and disable them as necessary, and notify the parent component when a button is clicked.

The non-obvious part of that is how to notify the parent component when a button is clicked, and I'm guessing that that's why you are trying to do all of that stuff in the renderer.

The trick to doing that is to specify 'cellRendererParams' in your column definition.
The value for 'cellRendererParams' can be anything you want (see https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/#complementing-cell-renderer-params).
In your case, you can pass in a call-back method. The renderer can get the call-back method in it's agInit() method, and call it whenever one of the buttons is clicked.